# 'LazyCorpusLoader' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I was doing some cleaning in the text with a func

```
def spacy_tokenizer(sentence):
    # Create token object from spacy
    docs = nlp(sentence)

    # Correct spelling
    tokens = docs._.outcome_spellCheck
    tokens = nlp(tokens)

    # Lemmatize each token and convert each token into lowercase
    tokens = [word.lemma_.lower().strip() if word.lemma_ != "PROPN" else word.lower_ for word in tokens]
    
    # Remove stopwords
    tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations]
    
    # Remove links
    tokens = [remove_urls(word) for word in tokens]
    
    # return preprocessed list of tokens
    return tokens
```

But it raise an error in this part tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations]

in specific:

```
<ipython-input-13-b662eacf73f8> in <listcomp>(.0)
     12 
     13     # Remove stopwords
---> 14     tokens = [word for word in tokens if word not in stopwords and word not in punctuations]
     15 
     16     # Remove links

TypeError: argument of type 'LazyCorpusLoader' is not iterable
```

Comment: What is `stopwords` and what is `punctuations`?

Comment: Stopwords is stopwords = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `LazyCorpusLoader` from NLTK (not `SpaCy`) is being iterated by you and it probably should not. `stopwords` is of `nltk.corpus.util.LazyCorpusLoader` type. You might want to use: `stopwords.words('english')` instead.

Please also check [this answer](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/53448/nltks-stopwords-returns-typeerror-argument-of-type-lazycorpusloader-is-not) from Data Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: strange, stopwords should be
stopwords = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS

Comment: Precisely! Otherwise, it is a mix of various libraries that overlap with functionality (namely, `SpaCy` and `NLTK`).